# Calculate ranking (match value) in Swiss tennis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

The match value is a part of the [ranking in Swiss tennis](https://www.swisstennis.ch/media/2718/2022_klassierungsrichtlinien_d.pdf), it is calculated with the formula:

$$
W=\frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left( \sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{w_i}+e^{w_0} \right)-\ln\left( \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{-w_j}+e^{-w_0} \right) \right)
$$

Original from the link above:
[image]

1. $W$ = your match value
2. $w_0$= your previous match value
3. $w_i$= the match value of the player you defeated
4. $w_j$= the match value of the player you lost to
5. $s$= sum of the matches you won
6. $N$= sum of the matches you lost

I would like to calculate how many times ($s$) one has to defeat a player with a match value of $W_j=3.400$ to get the match value $W=3.2$ if you start with $w_0=2.354$ for the setting when you do not lose matches ($N=0$).

How could I write a function in $\mathbb{R}$ to calculate this?

### Update1:

Because of the comments (the given formulas might not be unequivocal), I contacted Swiss Tennis for clarification. They sent me updated formulas (sorry for the quality, these are the originals):
[image]
[image]
Where `WA` = `W0`. Unfortunately, they did not provide an example of the formula in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$
W=\frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left( \sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{w_i}+e^{w_0} \right)-\ln\left( \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{-w_j}+e^{-w_0} \right) \right)
$$
could be clarified by changing the order of the summation within each $\ln$ function to make it as follows:
$$
W=\frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(e^{w_0} + \sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{w_i} \right)-\ln\left(e^{-w_0} + \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{-w_j} \right) \right)
$$
I believe that is the intention of the Swiss tennis group. If you sum the $e^{w_0}$ term $s$ times and the $e^{-w_0}$ term $N$ times, as the accepted answer does, then $W$ is undefined in the case of no losses. This is because in the case of no losses, $N = 0$ so the term with $N$ would be $\ln(0)$, which is undefined. Furthermore, if we use the new summation, if no matches have been played (so $s = N = 0$) we get
$$W = \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(e^{w_0}\right)-\ln\left(e^{-w_0}\right) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( w_0 + w_0\right) = w_0,$$
which is what we would expect: if no matches have been played then the player's $W$ value does not change from $w_0$.

Assuming that the players' scores only get updated after all the matches have been played (otherwise your competitor's score will change each time you beat them), we have the following $W$ after $s$ wins:
\begin{align*}
W(s) &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(e^{2.354} + \sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{3.4} \right)-\ln\left(e^{-2.354} + \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{-3.4} \right) \right) \\
W(s) &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(e^{2.354} + s e^{3.4} \right)-\ln\left(e^{-2.354} \right) \right) \\
W(s) &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(e^{2.354} + s e^{3.4} \right) + 2.354 \right)
\end{align*}
Rearranging gives
$$
2W(s) - 2.354 = \ln\left(e^{2.354} + s e^{3.4} \right),
$$
so
$$
e^{2W(s) - 2.354} = e^{2.354} + s e^{3.4},
$$
and then
$$
s = \frac{e^{2W(s) - 2.354} - e^{2.354}}{e^{3.4}}.
$$
Plugging in $W(s) = 3.2$ we get
$$
s = \frac{e^{2 \times 3.2 - 2.354} - e^{2.354}}{e^{3.4}} = \frac{e^{6.4 - 2.354} - e^{2.354}}{e^{3.4}} = \frac{e^{4.046} - e^{2.354}}{e^{3.4}} \approx \frac{46.64}{29.96} \approx 1.56.
$$
Since any $W(s)$ is clearly an increasing function of $s$, any value of $s$ greater than $1.56$ will work, so you need to win just $2$ matches. I get that after winning $2$ matches your $W$ value will be $3.30$ (to 2 d.p.).

In general you will need to win at least
$$
s = \frac{e^{2 W^* - w_0} - e^{w_0}}{e^{w_j}}
$$
matches to reach target $W^*$ by repeatedly winning against a player with match value $w_j$ where you start at match value $w_0$.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the correct interpretation of the formula, see my Update1.

Comment: Thanks @ava. I've made a correction to my other answer as I've spotted that R should be calculated differently

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you play the same player repeatedly without losing, the entire second half of the right side can be ignored, and the given equation simplifies to

$$\begin{align}
W &= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \sum_{i=1}^S e^{w_i} + e^{w_0} \right) \\[4mm]
&= \frac{1}{2} \ln \left[ S\left( e^{w_i} + e^{w_0} \right) \right]
\end{align}$$

This can easily be solved for $S$:

$$\begin{align}
2W &= \ln \left[ S\left( e^{w_i} + e^{w_0} \right) \right] \\[4mm]
e^{2W} &= S\left( e^{w_i} + e^{w_0} \right) \\[4mm]
S &= \frac{e^{2W}}{e^{w_i} + e^{w_0}}
\end{align}$$

and with the values you gave we get

$$\begin{align}
S &= \frac{e^{2(3.2)}}{e^{3.4} + e^{2.354}} \\[4mm]
&\approx 14.86
\end{align}$$

so you'd have to beat that player 15 times without losing to reach the match value you desire.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I tried to [write the function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051783/calculate-the-swiss-tennis-ranking-classification/76052096#76052096) but we get different results.

Comment: Thank you again. Could the formula stated above (original from the link) read as $\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{s} (e^{w_i} + e^{w_0})\right)$ or $\ln\left((\sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{w_i}) + e^{w_0}\right)$? See also update above.

Comment: Yes, it could also be read the second way; the reason I didn't interpret it like that is that if that were the case, it would have been much more reasonable/clear to write the expression as $\ln \left( e^{w_0} + \sum_{i=1}^s e^{w_i} \right)$. But then it's certainly possible the person who typed out the formula didn't have much of a mathematical bent.

Comment: I totally agree with you. See update above. I am sorry that the official formulas were equivocal.